# JSF Richfaces autocomplete problem -send hidden parameter using..anything

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsf, richfaces

Hy What i am trying to do si to create an autocomplete input text ,but when the form is submited i want to set an id or an employee Object, not to obtain the string from the input field.can someone help ..how can i use a hiddeninput field or an javascript / ajax function to do that.THX ..

```
<rich:autocomplete  mode="cachedAjax" tokens="," minChars="0"
            autoFill="true" selectFirst="true"
            autocompleteMethod="#{employeeBean.employeeSuggestions}" var="employee"
            fetchValue="#{employee.firstName} #{employee.lastName}">
             <h:inputHidden id="employeeId" value="#{employee.id}"/>
            <h:column >
                <h:outputText value="#{employee.firstName}" />
                <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{employee.lastName}" />
            </h:column>
        </rich:autocomplete>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="5">
        <h:commandButton value="#{messages.ok}"
            action="#{departmentBean.addOrUpdateDepartment}">
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton action="department" value="#{messages.close}"
            immediate="true" />
    </h:panelGrid>
```

i`m open to any suggestions.

Comment: This is a great question and perfect example of how utterly immature JSF and even the RichFaces extensions are. They deprecated rich:suggestionBox (presumably because it was flawed) in RF 4.x with the replacement being rich:autocomplete. However, this can only return a string with no possibility to bind and select an OBJECT (domain model, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same situation. The ultimate answer that I worked out is to use a jsFunction, combined with an action method in the backing bean.

First, the ID value will be fetched into the autocomplete field for a brief instant. The onselectitem JS function is called. The execute attribute of the jsFunction ensures that the fetched ID value is bound into the backing bean field before my populateEmployee action is called. populateEmployee turns around, moves the ID value in the field into wherever I want it, and replaces the value of the autocomplete field with whatever I ultimately want displayed (in this case, the name). Then the name autocomplete field is re-rendered.

Depending on how fast your backend system is with the employee ID-to-name lookup, the underlying ID will be displayed for a brief moment, while your equivalent of populateEmployee runs. But this is as close as I can get to an acceptable (in my case) working solution.

JSF:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="chooseEmployee" execute="employeeSearchName" action="#{employeeSearchBean.populateEmployee}" render="selectedEmployeeId employeeSearchName"/>
<rich:autocomplete id="employeeSearchName" mode="ajax" minChars="3"
                   autocompleteMethod="#{employeeSearchBean.searchEmployees}" var="emp"
                   autofill="false" layout="table"
                   fetchValue="#{emp.employee.id}" value="#{employeeSearchBean.selectedEmployeeName}"
                   onselectitem="chooseEmployee()">
... output columns ...
</rich:autocomplete>
<h:outputText id="selectedEmployeeId" value="#{employeeSearchBean.selectedEmployeeId}"/>
```

Backing Bean:

```
private String selectedEmployeeName;
private Integer selectedEmployeeId;

public void populateEmployee() {
  selectedEmployeeId = Integer.parseInt(selectedEmployeeName);
  for (EmployeeSearchEntry entry : data) {
    if (entry.getEmployee().getId().equals(selectedEmployeeId)) {
      selectedEmployeeName = entry.getNameLfm();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. Two problems with this - I forgot that the ID attribute of a component cannot be an EL expression. And the JS function in onselectitem cannot access the selected autocomplete entry - it is outputted to the client HTML as-is. I'll post up a refined answer in a moment with my more-convoluted working example.

Comment: Much thanks to the author but this only highlights the immaturity of JSF and even their showcase extension RichFaces. This work-around, with unwanted side-effects (because this use-case isn't really an auto-complete 'field' but an auto-complete with dynamic result set and object select capability) is very complex, introducing JS for which JSF proponents do not want added by developers versus using 'stock' components.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `a4j:param` within the JS function and assign param value to asignedTo Value.

And use event `onselectitem="chooseEmployee(this.value)"` in rich:autocomplete